# Loop through all buttons on a page and assign a new text value

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I've got a page that has several buttons on the page that have the same text assigned to them, and I'm working on localizing the page to a different language based on the user's browser culture.  I was hoping to programmatically cycle through them and relabel them on the fly.  This is what I've tried, and it causes an asp page error:

```
foreach (Button s in Page.Controls)
{
    if (s.Text =="search")
    {
       s.Text = "buscar";
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get a chance to catch exactly what the error was (had to revert the code so someone else could continue work on the page).  I will give the answer that was given so far a run, if for some reason it doesn't work, i'll reproduce the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), rather than looping through controls. So for example, with resource files in place, you can define a button like so:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnSave" Text="English Button" />`

The idea is that you will have a resx file for each language and culture you wish to support, and each file will contain the same labels e.g. "btnSave" but with differing text values.

I would strongly suggest you look into resource files as, in the long term, they will prove a lot more flexible for you.

Comment: seems like a better way of doing it.  For now i'll probably hack it using @ClaudioRedi's method to get it up and working for now, and refactor it to resource files in the near future.

Comment: marked as answer, as it's probably a much better way to do what i'm after in the long run.  I've upvoted the other posts that have helped too.

Answer (score 5):

Not all page controls are `Button`. Try with this

```
foreach (Button s in Page.Controls.OfType<Button>())
```

On the other hand, I totally agree with @Jason Evans that this is not the correct way to manage your string localizations. (I kind of missed the core of what you were trying to do in my first read)

Comment: This will also not find buttons recursively in child-controls.

Comment: I actually couldn't quite get this to work as was posted, but I've tweaked it a little bit to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    Button b = c as Button;
    if(b!=null)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
}
```